# Retrieve a value in Z3Py yields unexpected result

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to find a maximal interval in which an expression `e` is true for all `x`. A way to write such a formula should be: `Exists d : ForAll x in (-d,d) . e and ForAll x not in (-d,d) . !e`.

To get such a `d`, the formula `f` in Z3 (looking at the one above) could be the following:

```
from z3 import *

x = Real('x')
delta = Real('d')
s = Solver()

e = And(1/10000*x**2 > 0, 1/5000*x**3 + -1/5000*x**2 < 0)

f = ForAll(x,
And(Implies(And(delta > 0,
                -delta < x, x < delta, 
                x != 0),
            e),
    Implies(And(delta > 0,
                Or(x > delta, x < -delta),
                x != 0),
            Not(e))
    )
)

s.add(Not(f))
s.check()
print s.model()
```

It prints: `[d = 2]`. This is surely not true (take `x = 1`). What's wrong?

Also: by specifying `delta = RealVal('1')`, a counterexample is `x = 0`, even when `x = 0` should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Your constants are getting coerced to integers. Instead of writing:

```
1/5000
```

You should write:

```
1.0/5000.0
```

You can see the generated expression by:

```
print s.sexpr()
```

which would have alerted you to the issue.

NB. Being explicit about types is always important when writing constants. See this answer for a variation on this theme that can lead to further problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860633/936310

Comment: Ok, that was a problem. The formula seems to be wrong anyway, given that I want the max value: it gives `1/4`. Setting `delta = RealVal('1/4')` returns `x = 1/2` (true in fact). Setting it to `1/2` returns `3/4` and so on (should be `1`). Adjusting the `<` and `>` to `<=`, `>=` doesn't help. Trying with `ForAll x... and !Exists x ...` also doesn't produce the expected value.

Comment: Not sure what you make of your comment. Are you saying z3 is computing an incorrect model? If so, please formulate a new question and post it separately. (Note: I didn’t actually check your program for details, other than noticing that the constants were incorrectly coded.)

Comment: Yes. Ok, here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947472/incorrect-model-of-max-value-in-z3py