# Incorrect model of max value in Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to find a maximal interval in which an expression `e` is true for all x. A way to write such a formula should be: `Exists d : ForAll x in (-d,d) . e and ForAll x not in (-d,d) . !e`.

To get such a `d`, the formula `f` in Z3 (looking at the one above) could be the following:

```
from __future__ import division
from z3 import *

x = Real('x')
delta = Real('d')
s = Solver()

e = And(1/10000*x**2 > 0, 1/5000*x**3 + -1/5000*x**2 < 0)

f = ForAll(x,
And(Implies(And(delta > 0,
                -delta < x, x < delta, 
                x != 0),
            e),
    Implies(And(delta > 0,
                Or(x > delta, x < -delta),
                x != 0),
            Not(e))
    )
)

s.add(Not(f))
s.check()
print s.model()
```

Which outputs `[d = 1/4]`.

To check it, I set `delta = RealVal('1/4')`, drop the `ForAll` quantifier from `f` and I get `x = 1/2`. I replace `delta` with `1/2` and get `3/4`, then `7/8` and so on. The bound should be `1`. Can I get Z3 to output that immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the math yourself, you can see that the solution is `x != 0, x < 1`. Or you can simply ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F10000*x**2%20%3E%200%20%26%26%20(1%2F5000*x**3%20%2B%20-1%2F5000*x**2%20%3C%200)) to do it for you. So, there's no such `delta`.

The issue you're having is that you're asserting:

```
s.add(Not(f))
```

This turns the universal quantification on `x` into an existential; asking `z3` to find a `delta` such *that there is some x* that fits the bill. (That is, you're negating your whole formula.) Instead, you should do:

```
s.add(delta > 0, f)
```

which also makes sure that `delta` is positive. With that change, z3 will correctly respond:

```
unsat
```

(And then you'll get an error for the call to `s.model()`, you should only call `s.model()` if the previous call to `s.check()` returns `sat`.)

Comment: What's different between `s.add(d > 0, f)` and `f = ForAll(x, Implies(d > 0, ...)` in Z3?

Comment: Former is conjunction, latter is implication. With the former, you are telling z3 to find you a model making sure `d` is strictly positive and also `f` holds too. With the latter, you are telling z3 to find a model where you only care `f` holding when `d` is positive. That is, it can find you a model with `d <= 0` and completely ignore what happens with `f`, which isn't what you want. Note that this has nothing to do with z3 in particular, but just regular predicate logic. The difference between `p /\ forall x. q` and `forall x. p => q`, when `p` does not mention `x`.